# How to replace ^M with a new line in Perl

Tags: perl

My test file has "n" number of lines and between each line there is a ^M, which in turn makes it one big string.

The code I am working with opens said file and should parse out a header and then the subsequent rows. Then it searches for the directory path and file name. But because the file just ends up as a big string, it doesn't work correctly.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#use strict;
#use warnings;

open(DATA, "<file.txt") or die("Unable to open file");

my $search_string = "Directory Path";
my $column_search = "Filename";
my $header = <DATA>;
my @header_titles = split /\t/, $header;
my $extract_col = 0;
my $col_search = 0;

for my $header_line (@header_titles) {
  last if $header_line =~ m/$search_string/;
  $extract_col++;
}
for my $header_line (@header_titles) {
  last if $header_line =~ m/$column_search/;
  $col_search++;
}

print "Extracting column $extract_col $search_string\n";

while (my $row = <DATA>) {
  last unless $row =~ /\S/;
  chomp $row;
  my @cells = split /\t/, $row;
  $cells[74] =~ s/:/\//g;
  $cells[$extract_col] = $cells[74] . $cells[$col_search];
  print "$cells[$extract_col] \n";
}
```

When I open the test file in [vi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi), I have used:

```
:%s/^M/\r/g
```

and that removes the ^M's, but how do I do it inside this Perl program? When I tried a test program and inserted that `s\^M/\r/g`  and had it write to a different file it came up as a lot of Chinese characters.

Comment: prefer `open my $DATA, "<", $filename` to `open DATA, "<$filename"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before you start reading the file, set `$/` to `"\r"`. This is set to the linefeed character by default, which is fine for UNIX-style line endings, and almost OK for DOS-style line endings, but useless for the old Mac-style line endings you are seeing. You can also try mac2unix on your input file if you have it installed.

For more, look for "INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR" in [the perlvar manpage](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).

Comment: running dos2unix mac2unix I always get "Skipping binary file"

Comment: Did you try changing the input record separator as well?

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH... i reread your statement and I had $\ instead of $/

Comment: It says VOTE UP requires 15 reputation and I think I only have 6

Answer (score 5):

If mac2unix isn't working for you, you can write your own mac2unix as a Perl one-liner:

```
perl -pi -e 'tr/\r/\n/' file.txt
```

That will likely fail if the size of the file is larger than virtual memory though, as it reads the whole file into memory.

For completeness, let's also have a dos2unix:

```
perl -pi -e 'tr/\r//d' file.txt
```

and a unix2dos:

```
perl -pi -e 's/\n/\r\n/g' file.txt
```

Comment: Since when does `perl -p` read the whole file into memory?

Answer (score 0):

Did this file originate on a Windows system?  If so, try running the `dos2unix` command on the file before reading it.  You can do this before invoking the Perl script or inside the script before you read it.

Comment: This is actually the old pre-OS X Mac line ending. (Now they just use linefeeds) For some reason, Excel still exports CSVs with `\r` instead of `\n` at the end of lines. DOS files have both.

Comment: When I run the command I have been getting "Skipping binary file" .. I do believe the file permission at 644

Answer (score 0):

You might want to set $\ (input record separator) to ^M in the beginning of your script, such as:

```
$\ = "^M";
```

Comment: that didn't work.. when i entered it I tried just copy paste and doing `$\= "(ctrl V + ctrl M)"`

Comment: Your slash is pointing the wrong way, and "^M" is not how you express a carriage return in perl. It's `"\r"`

Comment: this one worked as well if you did `$/ instead of `$\`  Thank you

Comment: ok ^M is actually CR(carriage return). So you can use \r. Yes, I should use / instead of \. You might have to use $\="\n" after $/="\r" to change the output line terminator.

Answer (score 0):

perl -MExtUtils::Command -e dos2unix file

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19776067/edit), not here in comments (but *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).