# OSX - "sort" by 1st character only issue, tried -k 1.1,1.1

Tags: macos, bash, shell, unix, sorting

*I'm on OSX 10.6.8*

I'm having some issues sorting a text file by the first character.

I'm concatenating three files into one and need the final result sorted by the first alphabetical letter.
Each file has lines that look like this:

```
A025-001                                            
A118-001                                            
A118-002                                        
B657-001                                            
D316-001
```

So the file after concatenation via "cat" looks like this:

```
A025-001
....
A025-001 (where file 2 was appended)
....
A025-001  (where file 3 was appended)
```

I've tried "sort -k 1.1,1.1 result.txt > sortedresult.txt" and with a large amount of other options in the man page: i,b,f,s (just guessing in hopes that I may have found the right one)

I need all the entries to be put next to each other:

```
A025-001

A025-001

B.......

B.......

D.......
```

Hopefully, someone more knowledgeable than thou can help me solve this problem.

Thanks

Update: the data files themselves aren't working well with unix tools. If I cat the results file, only a few lines are shown, of many. Opening them in "vim" shows a bunch of ^M characters.  It seems as if sort is not going through the whole file.

There's column header at the top, with fields in quotations, tab-separated e.g. "Product" \t "Category" \t
The rest of the data is tab-separated but without quotations.
sample od -c:

```
    0000000    "   P   r   o   d   u   c   t       N   u   m   b   e   r   "
    0000020   \t   "   L   o   o   k   u   p       A   t   t   r   i   b   u
    0000040    t   e       1       G   r   o   u   p   "  \t   "   L   o   o
    0000060    k   u   p       A   t   t   r   i   b   u   t   e       1    
    0000100    N   a   m   e   "  \t   "   L   o   o   k   u   p       A   t
    0000120    t   r   i   b   u   t   e       1       V   a   l   u   e   "
    0000140   \t   "   L   o   o   k   u   p       A   t   t   r   i   b   u
    0000160    t   e       1       V   a   l   u   e       I   m   a   g   e
    0000200    "  \t   "   L   o   o   k   u   p       A   t   t   r   i   b
```

Here's some of the data (not the column header):

```
    0000660   "    \n  A   0   2   5   -   0   0   1  \t   F   a   c   e   t
    0000700   \t   F   a   c   e   t   C   o   l   o   r  \t   B   l   u   e
    0000720   \t   C   C   D   D   D   D  \t   O   P   T   I   O   N  \t  \r
```

Does anyone know why it is doing this?

Update #2: The files were exported out of FileMaker as ASCII. You'll see a lot of extra tabs, just ignore those, once we get this figured out I'll sed them out. Here is the entire file along with a hexdump and od -c of the file: pastebin.com/UzaUgG6C

Comment: Why not just a simple 'sort'?  What does it do that you don't want done?

Comment: do you want to keep the relative ordering of the entries in one file in the result file ?

Comment: A simple "sort" was the first thing I tried, expecting it to work, however, it doesn't seem to do the job for this case.
The entry relative to each file is sorted properly in the results file but they aren't being sorted together as a whole (A,A,B,B,C,C) which is what I need. FYI There are other columns (tabs) in input files: Category, Product Dimensions etc.

Comment: Your requirements sound as though a simple sort should do the trick; you say your results do not agree.  Maybe there is something odd about the data files after all.  Perhaps you should show us the first 10 lines or so of the output from `od -c` on the first couple of files: `echo file1.txt; od -c file1.txt | sed 10q; echo file2.txt; od -c file2.txt | sed 10q`.  Add it to the question itself; you can edit your own question.

Comment: That would explain why when I "cat" or "less" the files only a few lines are shown (not the full file). When I open them in "vim" it shows ^M all over the place. Using hexdump the lines are ended with the new line character, 0a.

Comment: I was expecting short lines as in the question; the data is of interest, but only shows at most one line.  There's a `\r` (carriage return, aka ^M) in there.  That normally means that the file spent some time on a DOS system.  However, at offset 0661, there is a newline `\n` (aka ^J) not preceded by `\r`.  I'm sorry to trouble you, but could you show some more of the data portion of the file.  I'm still not sure what's going on here.

Comment: 1. Can you remv all Ctrl-M's in the data? As you say it doesn't seem to be reading the complete file, if there are Ctrl-M's maybe there are Ctrl-D's as well(or Ctrl-Zs), which might mess up the sort.  2. Post a small set of sanitized data **that exhibits the same problem** to pastebin.com and add a link here so others can test. 3. Old `sort`s had problems with spaces as the 1st char. Some of your data looks to have a space char as the first in the line. I would think that with `-k 1.1,1.1` notation this wouldn't be a problem, but worth a try. 4. Try old style sort key `+0.0 -0.1`. Good luck.

Comment: No problem, I really appreciate the help. The files were exported out of FileMaker as ASCII. You'll see a lot of extra tabs, just ignore those, once we get this figured out I'll sed them out. Here is the entire file along with a hexdump and od -c of the file: http://pastebin.com/UzaUgG6C

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks guys, I wasn't aware that unix tools did not work well with DOS/Windows files. Learned a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is just the line endings. The `^M` characters are carriage returns. UNIX tools generally expect newlines, and no carriage returns. Try the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175977/how-to-replace-m-with-a-new-line-in-per) or try running `mac2unix` if you have it.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the pastebin, it seems FileMaker is terminating the column headers with \n and separating your records with \r. You need to normalize your line endings first.

```
cat result.txt | tr '\r' '\n' | sort
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try simply:

```
cat file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt | sort > result.txt
```

using the `-k 1.1,1.1` will not make any use as there is only one field

To make it stable, that is, the group of entries for which the first characters are same, will keep the relative ordering same, you might use the `-s` switch with the `-k 1.1,1.1` switch.

```
cat file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt | sort -s -k 1.1,1.1 > result.txt
```

I think this is the solution you need.

Comment: I tried this early today, and did it again just to be sure. Same results as the others. When I do a -s some of them are sorted properly, e.g. more A's will be next to each other than without the -s, however, If I scroll down in the text file, I still find unsorted A's from the appended file2 and file3 areas.

Comment: [UUOC](http://catb.org/jargon/html/U/UUOC.html)?  `sort -s -k 1.1,1.1 -o result.txt file[123].txt`?

Comment: UUOC: good point. Tried your suggestion, results are still the same though.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 sort -k1.1,1.2  result.txt > sortedresult.txt
```

I hope this helps.

P.S. as you appear to be a new user, if you get an answer that helps you please remember to mark it as accepted, and/or give it a + (or -) as a useful answer.